# Extracting json or object from POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have this data

```
models:"[{"timeTableId":5,"startTime":"2016-06-16T00:00:00","endTime":"2016-06-16T17:00:00","userId":31,"customerId":35}]"
```

being sent to a asp.net webservice using api.

We cannot determine how to extract the data for manipulation, we have tried...

```
public IHttpActionResult PostTimeTable([FromBody]string models);// models is null
public IHttpActionResult PostTimeTable(string models);// models is null
public IHttpActionResult PostTimeTable([FromBody]List<TimetableView> models);// models is null
public IHttpActionResult PostTimeTable(IEnumerable<TimetableView> models);// models is null
```

Where TimetableView is

```
public class TimetableView
    {

        public TimetableView(TimeTable timetable)
        {
            this.TimeTableId = timetable.TimeTableId;
            this.StartTime = timetable.StartTime;
            this.EndTime = timetable.EndTime;
            this.UserId = timetable.UserId;
            this.CustomerId = timetable.CustomerId  ;
        }

        public TimetableView(){}

        public int TimeTableId { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: what is your post method?

Comment: $scope.TimeTables = function(){
var crudServiceBaseUrl = "/api/cust",
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
update: {
url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/PostTimeTable",
dataType: "json",
type: "POST"},
},
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
if (operation !== "read" && options.models)
{
return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models )};
}
}

Comment: @Arvin in the end got this working 
Here is a link to the pastbin for this 
http://pastebin.com/p8HjFdeu

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public IHttpActionResult PostTimeTable(
       int timeTableId,
       DateTiem startTime,
       DateTime endTime,
       int userId,
       int customerId);
```

Comment: Hi @Arvin,
i have tried this and it still has not returned the correct extract the data

Comment: @Nageeth how do you write your post method?

Comment: public IHttpActionResult PostTimeTable(DateTime startTime,DateTime endTime,int userId,int customerId)
{sbhubEntitiesDB db = new sbhubEntitiesDB();
TimeTable table = new TimeTable();
 try
{table.UserId = userId;
table.CustomerId = customerId;
table.StartTime = startTime;
table.EndTime = endTime;
db.TimeTables.Add(table);
db.SaveChanges();

Comment: not this one, the method that would call PostTimeTable, and also add [HttpPost] attribute to your PosTimeTable as @Mr.B said

Comment: using postman with these fields work fine and it updates the database,
just when i try to update a field that already has data it does not seem to make the changes

Answer (score 0):

I have found out why this was not saving or getting the correct information and have solved this.
here is a link to the pastbin: http://pastebin.com/p8HjFdeu